# Prevent python2's TCPThreadingServer from calling handle on the request handler, on multiple requests

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to write a Network Application using Python's `socket` and `SocketServer` Modules.

- In the Network Model, there are only clients (nodes).
- Each node is connected to some other nodes(Neighbours) and can interchange "messages" with them.
- There are two types of messages `request_data` and `response_data`, the `response_data` string is a message generated based on a `request_data` message (messages are basically two line strings).
- In order for a Node to generate a `response_data` message, it must send `request_data` messages to the nodes it's connected to, and generate the `response_data` based on the received data.
- I'm implementing these Connections using `TCP` i.e: when two nodes are connected (using `socket.connect()` and `socket.accept()`) they will stay connected and will pass messages from the same connection.

Now here's the problem.

I've implemented the Nodes using `SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer` and a custom `request handler` so when a Node gets a `request_data` he sends `response_data`s to it's Neighbours, but when he gets the responses, the `ThreadingTCPServer` might capture it as a new request, (I assume that's how `select.select` works when there's data to be read) and I might not be able to get the response message from where I sent the request message, because instead a new `request handler` has been instantiated by the `ThreadingTCPServer`.

Basically I'm doing this in my request handler and I'm afraid it might not work:

```
# conn : a connected socket object created from socket.accept
conn.sendAll(requestMessage)
# I think this will not work because it might be considered a new request by the ThreadingTCPServer
response = conn.recv(1024)
```

I haven't actually tried this, and don't know if it will work or not, however even if it works for some limited tests I can't be sure it will always work since the problem(if it does in fact exist) stems from a race condition.

So does this work?if not what are some other approaches I can take without reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

This approach does indeed work, since TCP will open seperate ports for the conversation between the Nodes, and the it will have nothing to do with the port the server is listening on.